# Split line at point works unstable

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, line, splitting

I have two layers: lines and points. Points are snapped to lines.
The task is to split lines on the intersections with points.
[image]
In general, tool called Split Lines at Point works fine, as you can see on a picture (fig 1 and 2), but sometimes it makes mistakes like on fig.3 i.e. line isn't split.
I tried to specify the search radius but it didn't help.
What needs to be done in this case?

Comment: Recently I found a solution: before splitting lines at points it is important to make a topology check of the dataset including the layer of lines. Probably lines' geometry can be located not right on the coordinate grind in which points are. After simple topology check the whole line layer will be attached to grid (you even can see a difference with initial line layer) and then can be split by points without errors.